# preg_match with regular expression not working in php5.6.10?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, php-5.3

I am trying to match regular expression

```
/getData/?p<1d>[^/]
```

in `/getData/1`

using `preg_match` but this is not working with php 5.6.10 while it is working fine with php 5.3.8.

Please tell how do i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your working code in PHP 5.3.8?

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add brackets around the named capturing group `id` and also you need to remove `p` which exists before `<id>`

```
/getData/(?<id>[^/])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yC6vE7/1)

Comment: (?<1d> Group names must not begin with digits 
I get this error when try your method @Avinash

Comment: I thought it's an `i` . But I correctly included in the demo link i posted.